# Get Users which have been imported in Confluence via AD

Tags: postgresql, active-directory, confluence

Is there a way in the DB of confluence to get the number of users which have been imported via Active Directory? Like searching for a tag which identifies if a user has been imported or created on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can run following query against your database:

```
select u.id, u.user_name, u.active from cwd_user u
join cwd_membership m on u.id=m.child_user_id join cwd_group g on m.parent_id=g.id join cwd_directory d on d.id=g.directory_id
where d.directory_name='<External_Directory_Name>;
```

Replace the  with the name of your External User Directory. If you don't know the name maybe you can take it from following:

```
select * from CWD_Directory
```